# How to change mongoshell prompt?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I've recently re-installed Mongodb switching from the *enterprise* to the *community* version. Nevertheless, when I start `mongo`, this is the prompt format I get:

```
MongoDB Enterprise >
```

How can I change it to the standard prompt version? (i.e., `>` if I am not wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the prompt from *within* a shell session by setting the `prompt` variable. For example, issuing the following command within a Mongo shell ...

```
var prompt="this_prompt >"
```

... will result in the shell's prompt changing to:

```
this_prompt >
```

You can change the default prompt for all future sessions by updating your `.mongorc.js` (you'll find this in your $HOME directory and if it does not exist then just create it). The following addition to your `.mongorc.js` ...

```
var prompt=function() {
    return ISODate().toLocaleTimeString() + " > ";
}
```

... will result in this prompt:

```
:~/dev/tools/mongodb/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.4.7/bin$ ./mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.7
16:09:43 >
16:09:57 >
```

Or, to get this prompt: `>` just add the following to your `.mongorc.js`:

```
var prompt=">"
```

There remains the sub text to your question, namely; *where is the existing `MongoDB Enterprise >` prompt coming from?*. It's hard to say but ...

- Perhaps you have a Global `mongorc.js`; have a look in `/etc/mongorc.js` if you are on a *nix system or `%ProgramData%\MongoDB` if you are on Windows
- Mongo behavour when finding a rc file is also subject to environment variables, more details [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/program/mongo/#environment).

Comment: Great! It works. Interestingly enough, `.mongorc.js` was empty before my editing. Do you have an idea about where the default value is stored (in my case `MongoDB Enterprise >`)?

Comment: @floatingpurr I have updated the answer with some suggestions to address your last comment.

Comment: thanks. However, I've not a global version of `mongorc.js`. No idea about where default prompt format comes.

Comment: Uh...what if you have no prompt at all and setting a `prompt` variable has no discernible effect? Haven't tried messing with the mongrc yet. Just seems so weird that it's blank. Shell still works but there's no prompt at all.

Comment: Just confirmed changing mongorc does nothing either.

Answer (score 0):

When you search the internet for this topic then often you find the function below. If you like to include the existing prompt then use function `defaultPrompt()`, e.g.

```
prompt = function() {
    if (typeof db == 'undefined') 
        return '(nodb)> ';
    // Check the last db operation
    try {
        db.runCommand( {getLastError:1} );
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }

    var user = db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1}).authInfo.authenticatedUsers[0] 
    if (user) {
        return user.user + "@" + db + " " + defaultPrompt();
    } else {
        return "(anonymous)@" + db + " " + defaultPrompt();
        //return db + " " + defaultPrompt(); // if you prefer
    }
}
```

Prompts will be like this:

```
admin@mip mongos>

mip shard001:ARBITER>

admin@mip configRepSet:PRIMARY>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using defaultPrompt like this and it overrides everything else.

```
return "[" + username + "@" + database + ":" + privs + defaultPrompt() + "] >";
```

the output is the defaultPrompt without anything else. I would like to add if the connection is made to a mongos, or a PRIMARY or SECONDARY instance.